# tail recursive call in elixir and default parameters

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, default, tail-recursion, elixir

I am writing a simple example in Elixir and although it works I don't really understand how.

```
defmodule MyList do
  def sum([],acc \\ 0), do: acc
  def sum([head | tail], acc), do: sum(tail,acc + head)
end
```

When I call MyList.sum I get the expected result

```
sum([]) => 0
sum([1,2,3]) => 6
```

I cannot add a default param in the second sum because the compiler throws an error

```
def sum/2 has default values and multiple clauses, use a separate clause for declaring defaults
```

So my question is, how come sum([1,2,3]) works? It does not match any of the definitions.
Is the function still tail recursive?

Comment: I'd like to know if this is tail recursive or not myself.  I would think it _could be_ since you're not hanging on to anything that should force the code to create a stack frame.

Comment: It is tail recursive. I've updated the response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a multiclause with optional arguments, you can specify defaults as a body-less clause:

```
defmodule MyList do
  def sum(list, acc \\ 0) # sets up default arguments

  def sum([],acc), do: acc
  def sum([head | tail], acc), do: sum(tail,acc + head)
end
```

Regarding your example, I'm just guessing, but I think that your code amounts to something like following:

```
defmodule MyList do
  # implicitly generated due to default argument
  def sum(list), do: sum(list, 0)

  def sum([],acc), do: acc
  def sum([head | tail], acc), do: sum(tail,acc + head)
end
```

Which is why `sum([1,2,3])` works as well.

**Edit**:
The function is definitely tail recursive. If the last thing a function does is a call of another function (or itself), then it is a tail call. So in this case, when we call `sum(tail, acc + head)`, first the arguments are calculated, and then a tail recursive call happens.

Comment: So, regarding my question, is the default param inherited from the first definition to the rest? It looks like this is what is happening and it would explain why defining a bodyless clause works

Comment: Yes, the default param is inherited (or rather passed). The second snippet explains this. The code in that snippet is an expanded equivalent of your original code. Function `sum/1` will call `sum/2` sending 0 as the second argument. So each `sum/2` clause will receive this default value.

Body-less clause does the same thing,, but it seems more explicit and cleaner, since the default value is taken out of any clause and specified separately at the top.